# looking for a recommendation for Data structure for a sortable pair

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure s.t I could store a pair of `Integer` and `String`
and I'll be able to sort it twice: once by Integer descending order and once by lexical order.

I also want to be able to add a new pair dynamically.

for example: `{(13,a)(12,d) (9,a)}`

sort by numbers: `{(13, a) (12, d) (9,a)}`

sort by lexical order: `{(9, a) (13, a) (12, d)}`

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `Pair` which holds an integer and a string:

```
public class Pair {
    private Integer num;
    private String text;

    public Pair(Integer num, String text) {
        this.num = num;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getNum() { return num; }
    public String getText() { return text; }
}

List<Pair> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Pair(13, "a"));
list.add(new Pair(12, "d"));
list.add(new Pair(9, "a"));
```

Java 8 does support custom inline comparators when sorting, but in your case it appears that you want a two level sort, first by number, then by text (or vice-versa for the other comparator).  In this case, we define two custom comparators.  The second sorting condition is added via the `Comparator#thenComparing()` method in a chaining sort of fashion.  Then, we convert a stream into an actual sorted list.

```
Comparator<Pair> c1 = Comparator.comparing(pair -> -pair.num);
c1 = c1.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(pair -> pair.text));
Stream<Pair> pairStream = list.stream().sorted(c1);

List<Pair> sortedPairs = pairStream.collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("Sorting descending by number:");
for (Pair p : sortedPairs) {
    System.out.println("(" + p.getNum() + ", " + p.getText() + ")");
}

Comparator<Pair> c2 = Comparator.comparing(pair -> pair.text);
c2 = c2.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(pair -> pair.num));
pairStream = list.stream().sorted(c2);

sortedPairs = pairStream.collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("Sorting ascending by text:");
for (Pair p : sortedPairs) {
    System.out.println("(" + p.getNum() + ", " + p.getText() + ")");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sorting descending by number:
(13, a)
(12, d)
(9, a)
Sorting ascending by text:
(9, a)
(13, a)
(12, d)
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store a list of things with *order*, I suggest using a `List`.

The type that this `List` is going to store is `IntegerStringPair`, which is defined like this:

```
class IntegerStringPair {
    private int integer;
    private String string;

    public int getInteger() {
        return integer;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public IntegerStringPair(int integer, String string) {
        this.integer = integer;
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

Your list will be declared like this:

```
List<IntegerStringPair> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

To sort the list, you can do these:

```
// by integer
list.sort((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x.getInteger(), y.getInteger()));
// by string lexically
list.sort((x, y) -> x.getString().compareTo(y.getString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This really calls for a data class that isn't itself `Comparable` but is rather sorted using two different `Comparator`s.

The rest depends on your other requirements - is modifying the collection more common than reading it? Are you going to use `List` semantics (have duplicate items in the collection) or is it going to be a `Set`?. Depending on those, the structure holding the items might be anything from a `List` with two methods that copy and sort the list according to one of the two comparators, to two `TreeSet`s to hold pre-sorted values.